if $\nu^*(\mu,Y)=0$, then $\mu(Y)=0$?
I am reviewing a definition from the book Linear Operators by N. Dunford and J. Schwartz in Chapter 3, where it defines a set of measure zero. In this definition, it considers any subset $Y$ of $X$ and defines it as a set of measure zero when $\nu^*(\mu,Y)=0$. Here, $\mu:\mathbb{X}\to\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is an additive measure, and $\mathbb{X}$ is a field over $X$. Also, $\nu^*$ is the extension of the total variation $\nu$ of $\mu$ (defined by $\nu^*(\mu,Y)=\displaystyle\inf_{Y\subset A, A\in \mathbb{X}}\nu(\mu,A)$). My question is: if $\nu^*(\mu,Y)=0$, then $\mu(Y)=0$?
My general answer is no because Y is not necessarily in $\mathbb{X}$, although I am doubtful with the usual definition of a set of measure zero, whose only conditions are that $Y$ is in $\mathbb{X}$ and $\mu(Y)=0$. What is the difference between these two definitions?
I greatly appreciate your help and opinion on this.
